# How can component in iron-pages know when it is selected

Tags: polymer-1.0, dom-events, idioms

I have a Polymer 1.0 iron-pages element containing two custom elements:

```
<iron-pages selected="...">
  <my-page>A</my-page>
  <my-page>B</my-page>
</iron-pages>
```

I would like to take some action, like fetching ajax content, in my-page component, when the page becomes selected. How can I do this?

I came up with some ideas:

1. create a third component containing the iron-pages and wiring the events

   ```
   <dom-module id="my-controller">
     <template>
       <iron-pages selected="..." on-selected-changed="onPageChanged">
     ...
     <script>Polymer({...
       ...
       onPageChanged:function(){
         var page = ...;
         page.selected = true;
       }
   ```

   and

   ```
   <dom-module id="my-page">
     ...
     onSelected:function(){
       // fetch data
     }
   ```

   seems being rather much of an overhead to me, is this really necessary?
2. use `<iron-pages selectedAttribute="..." ...>`

   but I could not find a way to detect the attribute change in `<my-page>`

Are there common patterns to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was similar to your option A, but using events instead of method calls - its a more correct approach, and I'm actually baffled why [Polymer's ironSelectableBehavior](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/blob/master/iron-selectable.html) didn't implement it directly:

```
<iron-pages id="pages" ...>
   <my-first-page></my-first-page>
   <my-second-page></my-second-page>
</iron-pages>

...

<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',
    listeners: {
        'pages.iron-select': 'pageSelected',
        'pages.iron-deselect': 'pageDeselected'
    },
    pageSelected: function(e) { e.detail.item.fire('iron-select'); },
    pageDeselected: function(e) { e.detail.item.fire('iron-deselect'); })
});
</script>
```

Then, in your element, listen for these events:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-custom-element',
    listeners: {
        'iron-select': '_refreshData'
    },
    _refreshData: function(e) {
        // load some data
    }
});
```

Option B should also work - you probably need to set up the correct property and [put an observer on it](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers). In your component that contains `iron-pages` set up the attribute using the hyphenated form:

```
<iron-pages selected-attribute="activated" ...>
   <my-first-page></my-first-page>
   <my-second-page></my-second-page>
</iron-pages>
```

Then in your custom component set up the property and the observer:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-first-page',
    properties: {
        activated: {
            type: Boolean,
            observer: '_activationChanged'
        }
    },
    _activationChanged: function(newval, oldval) {
        if (newval) // == true
            console.log("just activated");
    }
});
```

Comment: meanwhile I learned to use option b) - I had two hurdles: The dashed-case attribute name and the correspondence between element attribute and polymer property

Comment: The camelCase-hyphenated duality is at the core of Polymer and one needs to understand that there is no spoon - it is you who needs to bend ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<iron-pages selected-attribute="visible"></iron-pages>

class MyClass extends PolymerElement {
  get activePage() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('iron-pages > *[visible]');
  }
}
```

(sorry for the zombie thread, but came looking for this).

Comment: nice, and then we can even watch it with an attribute listener